# The intersection of any collection of B.F.'s $\{F_{\alpha},\alpha \in A\}$. is the maximal B.F. contained in all of them

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Problem: The intersection of any collection of B.F.'s $\{F_{\alpha},\alpha \in A\}$. is the maximal B.F. contained in all of them; it is  denoted by $\bigcap_{\alpha \in A} F_\alpha$. (B.F.means borel field)

Solution:

1.We first show that the intersection of any collection of borel field is a borel field. 
(1) For $A_i \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in A}F_\alpha \Longrightarrow  A_i \in F_\alpha$ for $\forall \alpha \in A \Longrightarrow A_i^C \in F_\alpha$ for $\forall \alpha \in A \Longrightarrow  A_i^C \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in A}F_\alpha$.

(2) For $A_j \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in A}F_\alpha, 1\leq j<\infty$ , $\Longrightarrow \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}  A_i \in F_\alpha$ for $\forall \alpha \in A $ $\Longrightarrow \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}  A_i \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} F_\alpha$

2.We then show that the intersection of any collection of B.F.'s $\{F_{\alpha},\alpha \in A\}$. is the maximal B.F. contained in all of them.

It is trivial that $\bigcap_{\alpha \in A} F_\alpha \subseteq F_\alpha$ for $\forall \alpha \in A$\

In order to show $\{F_{\alpha},\alpha \in A\}$. is the maximal B.F. contained in all of them.  We need to show for arbitrary borel field $\widetilde{F}$ $\subseteq F_\alpha$ for $\forall \alpha \in A$ ,we have $\widetilde{F}\subseteq  \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} F_\alpha$

Choose arbitrary $A_i \in \widetilde{F}$, $\Longrightarrow$ $A_i \in F_\alpha$ for  $\forall \alpha \in A$, $\Longrightarrow$ $A_i \in F_\alpha$ for  $\forall \alpha \in A$, $\Longrightarrow$ $A_i \in \bigcap_{\alpha \in A}  F_\alpha$

Thus $\widetilde{F}\subseteq  \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} F_\alpha$.

Question: I can not make sure my proof.  Especially for the maximum part. Can any one give some suggestion? Many thanks!

The definition of Borel field is :

Borel Field:
(1)$E\in A\Longrightarrow E^{c}\in A$

(2)$E_j\in A; 1\leq j<\infty; \Longrightarrow \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j\in A$

Comment: What you have done is correct but in the last part you don't have a sequence $A_i$. You should just say $A \in \widetilde {F}$ implies $A \in \widetilde {F_{\alpha}}$ for all $\alpha$ which implies $A \in \cap_{\alpha} F_{\alpha}$.